# Creating unlimited dictionaries or lists

Tags: java

I need to get user input to either create lists, tuples, hashtables, etc. for ordered or key keeping. For example in python it would look like this when completed:

```
all = {'main1':{'name':'Hannag', 'birth':'date1', 'gender':'female'}, 'main2':{'name':'Kate', 'birth':'date2', 'gender':'female'}, 'main3':{'name':'Ben', 'birth':'date3', 'gender':'male'}}
```

In java I haven't figured out how to create a string key with more string keys inside of it. `main1':{'name':'Hannag', 'birth':'date1', 'gender':'female'}`
I've tried using tuples, but you can only do a set number from I what I've tried using tuple3.

```
        Map<String, Tuple3<String, String, String>> dos = new HashMap<String, Tuple3<String, String, String>>();
        while(adds.contains(contin))
    {
        String li = input.nextLine();
        String fName = input.nextLine();
        String fDir = input.nextLine();

        do.Add(fName, new Tuple3((String) li, (String) fName, (String) fDir));
```

I also tried using hashtable inside hashtable, but hashtable titles can't be strings. I need the names of hashtables or lists etc to be strings. Is there any way I could pull this off?

Comment: Sure, but more to the point, why are you trying to do this instead of writing a class with `name`, `birth`, and `gender` fields?

Comment: Agreed with @LouisWasserman.  I would recommend that you make a `List` of objects of the class that you define.

Comment: @LouisWasserman A little inexperience just started java maybe 2-3 weeks ago. Just trying whatever I can think of and have read or done before.

Comment: Java != Python.  You need to learn the Java way of writing code.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc That was just an example of what I wanted to happen thought it would make my question much clearer

Comment: Ok, let me try again.  Learning the syntax of a computer language is not nearly enough.  You must also learn the semantics of a computer language.  Listen to the people that are taking their time to write comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of messing around with tuples and maps, create a class:

```
class Person {
   final String name;
   final String birth; // maybe make this a Date?
   final String gender; // if you subscribe to the gender binary, maybe make this an enum?
   Person(String name, String birth, String gender) { // constructor
     this.name = name;
     this.birth = birth;
     this.gender = gender;
   }
}
```

and then have a

```
Map<String, Person> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("main1", new Person("Hannag", "date1", "female"));
...
```

Comment: Thank you for the example this really helps. Not just for this problem, but for others in the future problems.

Comment: What is the something you're trying to return?  Where are you trying to return it from?

Comment: If you haven't explicitly written a `getName()` method on `Person`, then you'll need to just do `main1.name`.  It's frequently good practice to write your own getter methods, but you'll need to do that explicitly.

Comment: @J.Doe remove the underscore.

Comment: @J.Doe you're probably better off creating a new question, making clear the changes you've made to the code, rather than trying to figure this out in the middle of this question.

Comment: You sure I don't want to bother to many people I honestly didn't even expect you to to reply again. Normally when people ask silly questions(like this) people tend to get mad.